# Chaining Asynchronous function dependent on result of Parent Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

What I am trying to do here is that based on the parent task execution I am trying to execute or cancel the subsequent async task. I am finding it hard to wrap my head around the execution of the following and trying to implement this in the most optimal way. I am looking for a way to write this in the most optimized way.

Also, I am confused as to why even after throwing up an exception it continues with the next iteration and await the task to figure out the exception thrown. I Can't find an explanation around this.

```
 public static async Task<TOut> AndThen<TIn, TOut>(this Task<TIn> sourceTask, Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> sf, CancellationToken cancelToken)
 {
        return await sourceTask.ContinueWith(async st => {
            var res = await st; // Raising cancel request in here.
            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return await sf(res);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted & TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled).Unwrap();
 }
```

Comment: Try `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled` rather than `&`.

Comment: What is the desirable outcome in case the `sourceTask` completes in faulted state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, [don't use `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Use `await` instead:

```
public static async Task<TOut> AndThen<TIn, TOut>(this Task<TIn> sourceTask, Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> sf, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
  var res = await st;
  cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  return await sf(res);
}
```

Comment: So, to handle the faulted state of the source task - wrap it with try catch ?

Comment: If you just want to propagate the exception, then do nothing; this code already does that. If you want to do something else, then yes, use try/catch.